# Turning on syntax highlighting for test script output to new buffer

Tags: syntax-highlighting, buffers

I'm using a plugin, [`bexec`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1788), to execute a test script. The plugin opens up a new buffer to the right of my code and it displays the output of the test script:

[image: terminal screenshot]

I would like to have syntax highlighting for the test script output. I'm using standard Perl testing modules (Test::More, etc.).

Can someone please point me in the right direction for making this happen?

Comment: What syntax highlighting are you looking for in the new window? Some new, custom one, or something already defined?

Comment: Something already define that will show warnings in red and passed tests in green.

Comment: I guess my first question is: how do I apply syntax highlighting to a buffer and how do I tell vim what syntax to highlight?

Comment: Did you took a look into `:h syntax`?